# how to connect google analytics 4 in google apps script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, web, google-analytics

Previously, my google apps script used universal analytics and dispatched events from the client side.

Connection example:

```
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-Y', 'auto');
ga('send', 'event')
```

Now i need to upgrade to GA4 and i changed my code to this

```
<!-- Google tag (gtag.js) -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-XXXXXXXXX"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());
  gtag('config', 'G-XXXXXXXXX');

  gtag('event', 'Name', {
   'event_category': 'Category'
 });
</script>
```

But it doesn't work at all. It is possible that Data Streams, which was automatically applied from the UA account, are incorrectly specified in the Google Analytics 4 account settings.